# Update image of SCNNode

Tags: ios, swift, scnnode

```
if (wallFrame == nil) {
  wallFrame = WallFrame()
  wallFrame.name = "Image"
}     
wallFrame.transform = SCNMatrix4((horizontalHit.anchor!.transform))
wallFrame.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(wallFrame.eulerAngles.x + (Float.pi / 2), wallFrame.eulerAngles.y, wallFrame.eulerAngles.z)
let positionz = SCNVector3Make(horizontalHit.worldTransform.columns.3.x, horizontalHit.worldTransform.columns.3.y, horizontalHit.worldTransform.columns.3.z)
wallFrame.position = positionz   
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
  let image = UIImage(named: "deer.png")
  elf.wallFrame.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = image
}
arView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(wallFrame)
```

I am creating a Custom SCNNode and trying to update the image content but it is not updating. How can I update SCNnode?

Comment: What is the type of `WallFrame`? Is it `SCNNode` or `SCNGeometry`?

Comment: It is SCNNode. SCNBox one

Comment: `SCNBox` is a subclass of `SCNGeometry`. Did you try creating a node from `wallFrame` and adding that node to the scene instead of `wallFrame` itself? Something like `SCNNode(geometry: wallFrame)`